# JMeter JSON Extract to extract random value which is not null

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using below JSON Extractor to extract random ItemID. It works fine but it also picks "null" value. Is there any way to extract random value from below json which is not null (i.e IT01 or IT02 in below example)

JSON path expression: $..ItemID
Match No (0 for Random) : 0**

[{
"ItemID": "null",
"deliveryId": "1",
}, {
"ItemID": "IT01",
"deliveryId": "2",
}, {
"ItemID": "IT02",
"deliveryId": "3",
}
]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The following JSONPath expression will give you all `ItemID` attribute values which are not null:

   ```
   $.[?(@.ItemID != "null")].ItemID
   ```

   [image]
2. So you can get a random match by providing `0` as the "Match No."

   [image]

   [image]

More information:

- [JSONPath Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JSONPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for your help, My JSON is in below format, but it returns even null value for this. Can you please help   $..[?(@.ItemID != null)].ItemID     
   {
 "Items": [
  {
                   "ItemID": null,
                  "deliveryId": "1",
  }, 
  {
                    "ItemID": "IT01",
                    "deliveryId": "2",
  }, 
  {
                   "ItemID": "IT02",
                   "deliveryId": "3",
  },
  {
                   "ItemID": "test",
                  "deliveryId": "3",
  }
    ]
}